# How to resolve ClassNotFoundException when the class is there?

Tags: java, exception, netbeans, compiler-errors

Here is my code

```
package vista;

public class MyMainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try
        {
            if(1>0) throw new MyException("ERROR");
        }
        catch(MyException err)
        {
            System.out.println(err.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
package vista;

public class MyException extends Exception
{
    // Constructor.
    public MyException(String errMsg)
    {
        super(errMsg);
    }
}
```

---

Output:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class vista.MyMainClass
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: vista/MyException
Command execution failed.
```

---

Both classes are in the same `\vista` folder, and before excecution NetBeans recognizes this. How do I resolve this?

---

Edit: while not running but just compiling the program I realized NetBeans was attempting to download some files. I turned my firewall off, ran the program, it downloaded some files, and now it excecutes properly.

Comment: The usual reason for this is a malformed or misconfigured classpath.

Comment: Aside from your actual problem, why do you throw an excet then immediately catch it? The exception isn't necessary.

Comment: @AndyTurner Oh I commented the rest of the code to just focus on what was causing the problem.

Comment: @Leo I appreciate you taking the time to do that.  A lot of people won't reduce their code to a minimal example for us.  Having something short and clear is really helpful for both answerers and future visitors.